# In supersonic flow, why must area increase in order to have velocity increase?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Based on the area velocity relation:

$\frac{dA}{A}=(M^2-1)\frac{du}{u}$

For M > 1, in order to increase u, we must increase A. I'm wondering what the explanation is physically and why it is opposite to that in subsonic flow.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/what-causes-acceleration-of-particles-in-the-expansion-section-of-a-de-laval-noz