# Why does gas that's been choked accelerate when the area it's passing through increases?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, rocket-science, bernoulli-equation

The throat of a rocket engine gets it up to sonic flow, and the bell of the engine gets it flowing even faster. But why does this happen? In subsonic flow the gas would slow back down, so why does this change for supersonic flow?

Comment: See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57497/

Comment: Nice discussion at the bottom of https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/nozzled.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes acceleration of particles in the expansion section of a De Laval nozzle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57497/)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas not in a satisfying way. The answer there just says "because of some equations." Either that, or I'm not properly equipped to understand.